# Adding JMenuItems to JMenu from results of ReGex through a text file in specific order

Tags: java, regex, swing, frame

In my JMenuBar I'm trying to add another JMenu with the name "Party" and in that menu have more menus that have items assigned to them.
The problem I'm having is either my ReGex isn't grabbing all of the proper values and I'm unsure as to how I would add them in the right order.

The text file I'm using for testing is as follows(with line numbers):

1. PC- Brandon
2. C- Dave
3. C- Bob
4. PC- CJ
5. C- John
6. C- Jim
7. PC- Hope
8. C- Elaine
9. C- Kim
10. C- Joe
11. PC- Ryan
12. C- Ted

I have the file loading in correctly however the ReGex doesn't seem to be grabbing all of the things it's supposed to.
The intended JMenu would look like so:

- Brandon

  - Dave
  - Bob
- CJ

  - John
  - Jim
- Hope

  - Elaine
  - Kim
  - Joe
- Ryan

  - Ted

With anything starting with "PC- " being a JMenu in the JMenu Party
and anything starting with "C- " being a JMenuItem under the respective JMenu
Here is my current code for this section.

```
void loadParty(File f, Frame frame, JMenuBar mb, JMenu me) throws FileNotFoundException {
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(f));
   List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
   JMenuItem item;
   me.setText("Party");
   JMenu subMen = new JMenu();

   while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
       text.add(scan.nextLine());
   }
   ArrayList<String> matchesCC = new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> charLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
   String regexCC ="^(C- )+(\\w+)+( : )+(http:(.*))";
   Pattern cc = Pattern.compile(regexCC, Pattern.MULTILINE);
   for (String s:text) {
       Matcher m = cc.matcher(s);
       if (m.matches()) {
           charLinks.add(m.group(4));
       }
   }

   String regexTest = "^((\\w+\\W+)(\\w+))";
   ArrayList<String> matchTest = new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> cT = new ArrayList<String>();
   Pattern dmTest = Pattern.compile(regexTest, Pattern.MULTILINE);
   for (String s:text) {
       Matcher m = dmTest.matcher(s);
       if (m.matches()) {
           for (int i = 0; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
                 System.out.println(m.group(i));
            }
           matchTest.add(m.group(2));
           cT.add(m.group(3));
       }
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < cT.size(); i++) {
       System.out.println(cT.get(i));
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < matchTest.size(); i++) {
      if(matchTest.get(i) == "PC- ") {
          subMen = new JMenu(cT.get(i));
          if(matchTest.get(i) == "C- ") {
              item = new JMenuItem(cT.get(i));
              item.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_0);
              item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                      for(int l = 0; l <charLinks.size(); l++) {
                          if(e.getActionCommand() == matchesCC.get(l)) {
                              URL = charLinks.get(l);
                              loadLink(URL);
                          }
                      }
                  }
              });
              subMen.add(item);
          }
      } 
          me.add(subMen);
   }
   frame.revalidate();
   frame.repaint();
 }
```

For some reason my ReGex of "^((\w+\W+)(\w+))" is only grabbing: (PC- Brandon
PC- Brandon,
PC- ,
Brandon,
PC- CJ,
PC- CJ,
PC- ,
CJ,
PC- Hope,
PC- Hope,
PC- ,
Hope) And nothing with a "C- "

Any help would be appreciated and if you need anymore info please just ask!

Comment: `The text file I'm using for testing is as follows` - I know nothing about regex's but your regex seems to be looking for "http" which would seem be to be the link you want to associate with the menu item. So I would suggest you haven't posted the text file that you are using? Because if that is the real text file you are using then I would say there is no need to use a regex, just use the `String.startsWith(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

First, forgive my pedantry, but "regex" is short for "regular expression."  The capitalization "ReGex" is nonsensical, because there is no word starting with a G.  "RegEx" would be acceptable, although in practice, there is no capitalization applied;  it is simply "regex" or "regexp".

You actually need far less regex functionality than you seem to think.  Rather than trying to read the entire file, and then parse the resulting giant blob of text, you should just process each line as you read it:

```
JMenu subMen = null;
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String itemType = scan.next();
    String label = scan.next();

    if (itemType.equals("PC-")) {
        subMen = new JMenu(label);
        me.add(subMen);
    } else {
        final String url = scan.findInLine("http\\S+");

        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(label);
        item.addActionListener(e -> loadLink(url));
        subMen.add(item);
    }

    scan.nextLine();
}
```

The above code assumes that each "C-" line is capable of matching your code's first regular expression.  As @camickr points out, the text lines you have shown in your question do not contain "http" in them at all, so the match would never succeed.  Be aware that showing data which isn't the data you're really dealing with makes your question considerably harder to answer.

You should not need to call frame.revalidate() or frame.repaint().  Both of those are handled automatically when you add components to a container, unless you are using a custom container and/or custom layout.